# What is the easiest way to make input delay

Tags: android

I'm a new android developer,

Due to security reasons, I want to make input delay in my sign in action, (Just showing a ProgressDialog for like 2 seconds and then continuing the main procedure). I already know how I can do it using MultiThread programming, but since there is nothing going on in the other thread, I thought maybe there can be some way to do it without using background workers.

I would be glad if you could tell me an easy way to do it in android

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Action Bar Sherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) you don't need threading. Just call

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean)
```

i think learning this api harder than using threads but new generation Android (after api 11) apps generally use action bar progress.

Comment: that's a good idea, But I'm writing the application for api level 9, And as far as I know ActionBarSherlock doesn't work there

Comment: No, current min is api 7. Offical action bar api level is 11.
You can check sherlock's manifest from this link; https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/AndroidManifest.xml. You'll see android:minSdkVersion is 7

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the main thread for 2 sec.

Comment: If you mean Thread.sleep(), that would make the progressDialog to stop as well, And I don't want that

Answer (score 0):

Well, just for the future reference, I found another way to solve this problem using **Timer**, I think it's better than **Background Thread**, I created a wrapper function which calls the main event after an specific amount of time

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "sometitle", "somecontent");

        /**
         * input delay
         */
        Timer delayWorker = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public View view = null;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                onClickAction(view);
                this.cancel();
            }
        };

        task.getClass().getField("view").set(task, view);
        delayWorker.schedule(task, INPUT_DELAY);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        /**
         * error occurred
         */
    }

}


private void onClickAction(View view) {

      /**
       * actual action click
       */

 }
```